# How to hide loading indicator of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to hide the loading indicator offscreen to the left. Right now it is partially showing as shown in the [GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/qfnFbRKgdj5CPnaCp2/giphy.gif). How do I fix that ?

```
refreshIndicator = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero, type: .circleStrokeSpin, color: Constants.loadingIndictorColor)
            refreshIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(refreshIndicator)
            refreshIndicator.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.centerY.equalToSuperview()
                make.size.equalTo(Constants.loadingIndicatorSize)
                refreshConstaints = make.right.equalTo(view.snp.left).offset(sideInset).constraint
            }
            refreshIndicator.startAnimating()


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            let offSet = scrollView.contentOffset.x
            if offSet < (sideInset) {
                refreshConstaints?.update(inset:-offSet)
            }
    //        if offSet > +100{
    //            refreshIndicator.stopAnimating()
    //        }
            else{
                refreshIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set "Hides When Stopped" in AttributesInspector

or in code

```
refreshIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
```

[image: LOOK]